# ecache store and retrieve the values from disk storage

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, disk

I am using ehcache for one of my requirement. It has to store some key value pairs into disk storage and retrieve from web server several times using multiple request.

But am getting null pointer exception while try to retrieve from another instance using the same cache.

configuration ehcache.xml:

```
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cache name="cache1" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
        eternal="false" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

kindly any one help as to do it properly.

Sample code:

```
//1. Create a cache manager
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.newInstance();

//cm.addCache("cache1");

//2. Get a cache called "cache1", declared in ehcache.xml
Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache1");

//3. Put few elements in cache
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
    cache.put(new Element("key"+i,"cache"+i));
}

//4. Get element from cache
Element ele = cache.get("key2");

//5. Print out the element
String output = (ele == null ? null : ele.getObjectValue().toString());
System.out.println(output);

//6. Is key in cache?
System.out.println(cache.isKeyInCache("key3"));
System.out.println(cache.isKeyInCache("key101"));

//7. shut down the cache manager
cm.shutdown();
```

Another class for retrieve from cache:

```
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();
if(cm.cacheExists("cache1")){
    System.out.println("chache is working...!!");
    Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache1");
    Element ele = cache.get("2");
    Serializable value = ele.getValue();
    System.out.println(value.toString());
} else {
    System.out.println("chache is not working...!!");
}
```

Comment: i guess when you retrieve, you missed to add "key" literal in the key. Element ele=cache.get("key2");

Comment: am sorry that was actually i missed key but even i put key i cont able to retrieve the value .  System.out.println( cache.getDiskStoreSize()); for above code am getting "101"  i did the same with retrieve code output is "0"

Comment: can you explain more about your configuration of the ehcache, and on both of your classes, how runs them? are the both in the same assembly?

Comment: need more info - configuration and when it is invoked, whether the first class after putting is it able to retrieve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that you should pay attention to:

1. `CacheManager.getInstance()` and `CacheManager.newInstance()` are not identical. The first one will create a cache manager with the default configuration and associate it to be the *singleton* cache manager. The second one will not do this association. It probably does not affect you, but this could be important depending on the setup.
2. Your sample code shuts down the cache manager, which means that unless the two bits of code run concurrently, they will never see the same `CacheManager`, `Cache`s or data.

It is recommended that you create and shut down the cache manager in one place - like a `ServletContextListener` - using one of the methods that allows you to specify the exact configuration file to load.

And then simply access it using `CacheManager.getCacheManager(String name)` in code that needs to use it.

Note: You may want to edit your question to indicate what's your output from running your sample code. This may impact this answer.